# Gulp Usemin not doing anything

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-usemin

I have multiple apps in one project, so I have this task:

```
gulp.task('usemin', function() {
  return gulp.src('/app1/index.html')
    .pipe(usemin({
      js: [ uglify(), rev() ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app1/build/'));
});
```

And this is the index.html:

```
<!-- build:js app.js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
.
.
.
<!-- endbuild -->
```

The task runs without issues but generates no file!

Answer (score 0):

You're using an absolute path here:

```
return gulp.src('/app1/index.html')
```

You probably want to use a project relative path:

```
return gulp.src('app1/index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried appending to relative path on gulp.src?

```
return gulp.src('./app1/index.html')
```

Read the [Doc](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md) for more details.